# package manager broken and libjack errors after using BleedingEdge12_4_26.sh

Tags: package-management

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 lts. I used the BleedingEdge12_4_26.sh script which was recommended to me to install some more software.

This morning my update notification came up and when I tried to do an update I started getting errors about the package manager being broken. The package manager log revealed that libjack was the problem.

I tried to install it manually but this is what I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libjack-jackd2-0
[sudo] password for jls: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  jackd2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjack-jackd2-0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3 072 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 207517 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libjack-jackd2-0 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1 (using .../libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libjack-jackd2-0 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack- jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems like some kind of conflict but I am unable to decipher exactly what.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**Update:** After some more research I tried this:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which returned this:

```
Fetched 2 574 kB in 17s (144 kB/s)                                                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-jackd2-0 : Breaks: libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (!= 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1 is installed
 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 : Breaks: libjack-jackd2-0 (!= 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1) but 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So i tried this:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

which returned this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjack-jackd2-0
Suggested packages:
  jackd2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjack-jackd2-0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3 072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dns/sound/ubuntu/ precise/main libjack-jackd2-0 amd64 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1 [197 kB]
Fetched 197 kB in 1s (101 kB/s)            
(Reading database ... 207517 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libjack-jackd2-0 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1 (using .../libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libjack-jackd2-0 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

jls@jls-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (--configure):
 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1 cannot be configured because libjack-    jackd2-0:amd64 is in a different version (1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libjack-jackd2-0:i386
```

So I tried to remove the conflicting package;

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libjack-jackd2-0
```

And ended up with this;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 libasound2-plugins : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 libavdevice53 : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 libfluidsynth1 : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 libmlt4 : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 libportaudio2 : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 librtaudio4 : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 librtmidi1 : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
 lmms : Depends: libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or libjack-0.116
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And now I'm really stumped :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

After trying

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**and**

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
$ sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status    (you can use vi or nano instead of gedit)
Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.
```

Comment: Thanks ptheo.  I commented out the libjack block and tried another update but got this:                                     Fetched 2 291 kB in 2min 17s (16,7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  


W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to remove something in the block. I tried ptheo solution and it's the only one that worked for me (after many other tries and reading many other questions here about an i386 package stuck in an half-configured state, just because the amd64 version was in a more recent version...).

Comment: Thanks Claude. You were right. There was a second libjack block further down in the file.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [multiple places](http://askubuntu.com/a/245845). When tempted to do so, this typically means: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.