# dpkg: error processing linux-headers-3.2.0-35

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, synaptic

Whenever I install, update or uninstall a program in the terminal, this comes up

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 11.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 251024 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae ...
dpkg: error processing linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae (--remove):
 unable to securely remove ': File name too long
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried purging dpkg, but the same error from terminal. Aptitude also doesn't work! Any solutions to fix it ?

Comment: I don't have an answer (wish I did) but rather a question - why do you want to remove this package?

Comment: I don't want to remove them, it runs on its own in the middle of any installation or update. It aborts when I enter 'n'.

Comment: I see. Sorry not to be able to help further, this is out of my league.

Comment: Hope somebody else will, Thank you @ClivevanHilten

Comment: "I also tried purging dpkg" - Hold on a sec! You sould never remove `dpkg`! It's an essential system package for package management, used by all APT tools. It seems that your dpkg database is screwed up in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae.list`. (the cause, not a solution/answer yet)

Comment: Please give an example of the command you are running, with the full output.

Comment: @gertvdijk yeah I read similar problems, but all others used force remove which in my case can't be done!

Comment: @PaddyLandau `sudo apt-get autoremove
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y` and thee rest like in the question!

Comment: @Andrew Please **edit** your question with new information. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. I'm quite sure your package management is just screwed up (completely). See my earlier comment. The `unable to securely remove ': File name too long` error **should never happen**.

Comment: @gertvdijk This is just one instance of the error, so I hadn't included it earlier. Only solution to reinstall ?

Comment: @Andrew I cannot determine from here to what extent your package management database is broken. Keep in mind that this does not break by itself. This is a clear indication of data corruption or a very very severe and unlikely bug.

Comment: Ok then I'll reinstall the OS, even upgrade to 12.10 doesn't work! Thank you @gertvdijk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu software updater did the work. A partial upgrade option was available and the generic lists were updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

After trying

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
$ sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status    (you can use vi or nano instead of gedit)
```

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

Comment: Thank you @ptheo, the problem's gone now but I'm not able to post the answer until 8hrs after I posted the question. Software updater did the work smooth. I referred to that link earlier and I couldn't find which one was corrupt!

Comment: Modifying the `dpkg/status` file yourself is asking for trouble. Now there are several files on your system in system directories the package manager is not aware of. Now it won't be possible to uninstall the package properly and you're likely to run into more issues during upgrades and such.

Comment: Ok. Its my fault posting the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @ptheo I recommend deleting (or better, customizing) one.